Difference Between X-Ray Interaction in XRD and XRF?
Here are the beginning explanations for both XRD and XRF.

X-Rays bombard a sample.

However, one process looks at constructive reflection, while the other looks at the photon emitted by absorption by the sample.
I KNOW that both processes collect different information, but if both processes involve the same first step, why does one process reflect while the other absorbs? Does not absorption and reflection by the sample happen at the same time? Is it just a matter of what the detector has been trained to pick up?

Normal things all around you both reflect and absorb light, including X-rays.

So does it come down to the sensor?

XRD is diffraction of xrays of a crystalline sample, i.e. scattering of xrays off planes of atoms and no energy goes into the atoms.   XRF involves exciting an atom by absorbing xray energy. The atom  looses a tightly bound  electron and then another electron fill the 'hole' left and an xray photon ( fluorescence) is emitted. The emitted photon energy is characteristic of the atom.

@porphirin "No energy enters atoms" this is not exactly true. By diffraction we detect (and we only want to detect) coherent scattering, but in reality incoherent scattering also occurs when the sample is irradiated.

X-ray fluorescence (XRF) is an electronic relaxation. If one considers electrons as particles, X-ray radiation is absorbed and a inner electron is excited; it leaves an unoccupied place in an orbital. Electrons of already higher energy (for which the absorbed radiation was not suitable for their excitation) "fall" into this "gap" while emitting a radiation characteristic for the corresponding element (e.g., the $K\alpha$ and $K\beta$ lines). The wavelength of excitation typically differs from this wavelength of fluorescence (EDX analysis). Detection limits of the experiment aside, a single atom suffices for this process.
The underlying principle of diffraction analysis of single crystals (scXRD) and powders (PXRD) is Bragg's equation
$$n \lambda = 2d \sin \theta$$

(image credit Hydrargyrum@Wikipedia)
i.e. the gradual adjustment of the orientation of light source,1) sample, and detector can pass maxima of intensity (because of constructive interference by difference in pathways) and minima (because of then destructive interference) recorded on the detector if i) there is good enough periodicity in the spatial arrangement of objects in the sample,2) and ii) the incident wavelength is about the scale of this periodicity.3) Contrasting to XRF, the XRD experiment requires an ensemble of (many) multiple atoms.
Because XRF itself is a source of X-ray radiation, it creates a secondary diffraction (with own exciting wavelength) which is recorded simultaneously to the one of original interest. To prevent this unwanted complication of the diffraction experiment (diffractometer CCD cameras typically don't discern different wavelengths of X-ray radiation) the selection of the wavelength equally considers the elemental composition of the sample. This is one reason why there are XRD tubes with different targets, i.e. anodes of Cu, Mo, Fe, Ag, etc.

1) While the question is about XRD/X-rays, at the scale of analysis of a XRD analysis, the incident light can be X-rays, but equally can be neutrons, or electrons. And though arguably most diffractometers use a monochromator between light source and sample, the Laue technique (a setup of a sample in front of white X-rays, a continuous spectrum of incident radiation) has its value e.g. for time resolved crystallography of enzymes and proteins (see Moffat, and Vallejos et al. as entries), too.
2) At this scale, good periodicity of the objects in space contributes to good/high crystallinity of a sample.
3) One reason why angstrom ($\pu{1 Å} = \pu{1E-10 m}$), though not a SI unit, enjoys popularity beside picometre ($\pu{1 pm} = \pu{1E-12 m}$) and nanometre ($\pu{1 nm} = \pu{1E-9 m}$) in some fields of and around crystallography. Say for instance the aromatic $\ce{C-C}$ bond in benzene of about $\pu{1.38 Å} = \pu{138 pm} = \pu{0.138 nm}$.
Moffat, K. Laue Diffraction and Time-Resolved Crystallography: A Personal History. Phil. Trans. R. Soc. A. 2019, 377 (2147), 20180243. https://doi.org/10.1098/rsta.2018.0243 (open access).
Vallejos, A.; Katona, G.; Neutze, R. Appraising Protein Conformational Changes by Resampling Time-Resolved Serial x-Ray Crystallography Data. Struct. Dyn. 2024, 11 (4), 044302. https://doi.org/10.1063/4.0000258 (open access).

Diffraction (which is not simply reflection) involves elastic scattering between the X-rays and the sample; on the contrary, the fluorescence is given by an inelastic scattering interaction.
The mechanisms of these interactions are very different. Indeed, they can occur simultaneously (along with other types of interactions), but the instruments are designed and optimized for each analytical technique. So the instruments are optimized to exclude some kind of signals.
If you perform an X-ray diffraction analysis of a crystalline Fe-oxide using a Cu anti-cathode, you will notice diffraction peaks of the crystalline material and a strong background due to fluorescence. This is because the X-ray wavelength has an energy very close to the absorption edge (inelastic interaction) of Fe. This is a clear demonstration that diffraction and fluorescence occur at the same time.

So I found this with a google search. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/RD-patterns-of-as-prepared-and-annealed-iron-oxide-nanoparticles_fig1_275348387; so the peaks are constructive waves, but the high red is due to the fluorescence intensity also hitting the sensor.  What does an XRF Sensor do to emphasize the fluorescence and not the peaks? Can peaks occur in an XRF graph?

WAIT: Taking a look at the diagrams, I recall that XRD captures returns at angles, and XRF is stationary. Further, XRF has an analyzer crystal that takes the emitted light and diffracts it, cleaning up the signal into parts (a diffraction grating sharpens features from continuous to distinct parts that are constructively interfering). However, I can see how the same process produces the same results, but that the method of receiving the signal is what is different. Can you mention something about the machine set-ups in your response?

You'd better revise the basis of these different analytical techniques. In general, in a diffraction experiment, you use an X-ray beam with fixed energy (wavelength) and obtain diffraction peaks at different scattering angles. Each peak corresponds to an interplanar spacing in the structure. In an XRF analysis, you scan an energy range (you use an X-ray beam with a variable energy range) and obtain a spectrum where each peak corresponds to an energy level of each particular element constituting your sample. By diffraction, you gain information on structure, by XRF on chemical composition.

One of the main differences is distance from the sample, yes? Scattering is picked up far away based on the machine I have seen, and photons need to be picked up rather close, and thus XRF Hand Guns Exist. Noting your recent comment, XRF has X-Ray Intensity on the X and UA on the Y, and XRD has 2-theta on the X and UA on the Y?

You write 'at the same time ' but not from the same atom at the same time there is a probability one or the other happens.
